# How to manipulate a received svg (access '<g>' and '<rect>' elements) via vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-html-loader

I'm getting several SVG's that are all structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg>
    ...
    <g id="cabin">
        <g id="1">
            <g id="a">
                <rect />
                <path />
            </g>
            <g id="b">
                <rect />
                <path />
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="2">
            <g id="a">
                <rect />
                <path />
            </g>
            <g id="b">
                <rect />
                <path />
            </g>
        </g>
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

I'm loading the SVG via the `html-loader`

```
<div ref="plan" v-html="require('!html-loader!../assets/plaene/plan_1.svg')"></div>
```

I'm trying to access all child notes of `cabin` to change the `style` of the `rect` items. How should I do this? I tried this before in a single `html`-file with plain `javascript`

```
var plan = document.getElementById("plan");
plan.addEventListener("load",function() {
    dom = plan.contentDocument;
    let cabins = dom.getElementById('cabin');
    ...
    and so on
```

but I don't know how to do this in `vue`. I have read some articles (e.g. [VueJS — Tips & Best Practices](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vuejs-tips-best-practices-39d9962bb255)) which say that you shold **avoid manipulating the DOM directly**, so I guess there must be something else.

Has somebody a solution for this? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it an option to create the SVGs dynamically as Vue components instead of loading them from files? This way, you could render your SVG dynamically using Vue's reactivity. Would give you a lot more flexibility regarding the styling. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q-59031887-z6kd2

Comment: Hey @wwerner, thanks for your answer. The problem is that I'm getting the SVG's from an external source. In your example you already add `attributes` like `width` or `heigth` as `props` in the component, which I am missing in my 
predetermined SVG's. I need to access the `<g>` and `<rect>` somehow, to add my styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
let numbers = [1, 2]
let g_tags = this.$el.getElementsByTagName('g')

let svg_root
g_tags.forEach(el => {
    if(el.getAttribute('id') === 'cabin') {
        svg_root = el
    }
})

svg_root.children.forEach(obj => {
     let id = obj.getAttribute('id')

     if (numbers.includes(parseInt(id))) {
         obj.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.setAttribute("style", "fill: green")
         obj.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.setAttribute("style", "fill: green")  
     }
})
```

I guess by using `this.$el` I access the virtual and not the real `DOM`, so it should be "legal". Please let me know if I'm wrong and there is a better solution.